# How to use Table valued parameter in Stored Procedure and then call it in MVC C# Visual studio?

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net-mvc, stored-procedures, table-valued-parameters

I have created user defined datatype which is of type table as:

```
Create type Employeetable as Table
(
    FirstName varchar(50),
    LastName varchar(50), 
    States varchar(50),
    City varchar(50), 
    AddressLine1 varchar(100),
    AddressLine2 varchar(100)
)
```

But now I am consfused as to how should I use it in stored procedure , doing a basic CRUD operation here . THis is how i have used Create Procedure:

```
Create Procedure InsertEmployees
    @employeetable Employeetable Readonly 
as
begin
    Insert into Testing.Employees
    select * from @employeetable
end
```

Also I don't know how to use it in MVC C# in visual studio because when I added stored procedure it showed this error:

> Error 6005: The function 'InsertEmployees' has a parameter 'employeetable' at parameter index 0 that has a data type 'table type' which is currently not supported for the target Entity Framework version. The function was excluded

Also in controller how should I proceed with the code , in normal stored procedure I would write these in [HttpPost]:

```
public ActionResult AddProduct([Table name] [table object])
{
ObjectParameter objParam = new ObjectParameter("productID", typeof(int));
int result = 
db.usp_SAVE_tbl_Products_PG_ADODotNetDemoCode(objProduct.ProductID, 
objProduct.ProductName, objProduct.Rate, objProduct.Quantity, objParam);
this.db.SaveChanges();
int resultVal = Convert.ToInt32(objParam.Value);
return RedirectToAction("ListProducts");
}
```

Kindly help with this thanks

Comment: The error message is clear - the version of EF you are using does not support table valued parameters. I personally have no experience with EF so I don't know what version does support it but I'll bet it's documented...